# PHP Form doesn't insert into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, insert

I'm trying to make a form and upload that into my database, but it doesn't work.
This is my HTML Code:

```html
<form name="Form-Request" method="post" action ="icn/form.php">
    <div>
        <p><input type = "text" placeholder="Name" name = "name"></p>
        <p><input type = "email" placeholder="Email-address" name = "email"></p>
        <p><input type = "text" placeholder="Virtual Airline" name = "va"></p>
        <p><input type = "text" placeholder="Virtual Airline (IATA Code)" name = "va-iata"></p>
        <p><select name="pricing">
            <option>Free</option>
            <option>Business</option>
            <option>Pro</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><select name="vam-vms">
            <option>PHPVMS</option>
            <option>VAM</option>
        </select></p>
        <p><input type = "text" placeholder="Additional Info" name = "add-info"></p>

        <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

and this is my PHP post file, I have entered the database details but I don't want to share it :):

```html
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$va = $_POST['va'];
$vaiata = $_POST['va-iata'];
$pricing = $_POST['pricing'];
$vamvms = $_POST['vam-vms'];
$additionalinfo = $_POST['add-info'];

<?php
$servername = "host";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO request_site (Name, Email Address, Virtual Airline, Virtual Airline IATA, Pricing, VAM/PHPVMS, Additional info)
VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$va', '$vaiata', '$pricing', '$vamvms', '$additionalinfo' )";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with _it doesn't work_ ? You're open to SQL Injection

Comment: Columns usually do not have spaces. If the column names in your table have spaces, you'll need to surround the column names with backticks. Checking explicitly for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) will point out what is wrong with your query.

Comment: Surround all of your table columns with backticks. `INSERT INTO request_site (\`Name\`, \`Email Address\`, \`Virtual Airline\`, \`Virtual Airline IATA\`, \`Pricing\`, \`VAM/PHPVMS\`, \`Additional info\`)` if those are your actual table columns.

Comment: Also, you are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur in your values,** but will not help with column names.

Comment: I've never had to use backticks in queries which is why I get instant headache when I see them in code :o

Comment: Still doesn't work... what do you mean with SQL Injection?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you should do with this code.

First, since you're trying to use every field in your form, you should add the `required` attribute to each input field.

Second, since you're submitting a post request, I would suggest that you check in your PHP script if the request is a POST and check if the values you're attempting to get from the POST exist. This will prevent someone from simply navigating to your script and trying to execute it improperly:

```
<?php
if (
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && 
    array_key_exists('name', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('email', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('va', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('va-iata', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('pricing', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('vam-vms', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('add-info', $_POST)
  ) {
  /* ... */  
} else {
  http_response_code(401);
}

?>
```

Third, don't use `mysqli`. The [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) has been out since PHP 5.1.0 and is the preferred method of connecting to databases. In this case, use a Try/Case statement to attempt to establish a PDO connection:

```
try {
  /* database configuration */
  $servername = "host";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "dbname";

  /* establish a PDO connection */
  $dsn =  "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$servername;charset=utf8mb4";
  $db  =  new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
  $db  -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $db  -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

  /* run SQL query */
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
  /* handle database error */
}
```

Fourth, you'll need to tweak your SQL statement a bit, I think that this is where it is causing some errors. It is generally best practice to escape the column name using back-ticks, but in this case since it looks like your column names have spaces in them, it is actually necessary (plus `name` might be a keyword too). It is also best practice to use parameters as to prevent for SQL injection. The idea is that you pass a user-defined name in the SQL query with a `:` prefix and that name corresponds to a value defined in an array that gets passed:

```
/* Insert all the values in the request_site */
$stmt = $db->prepare('
INSERT INTO `request_site` (
  `Name`,
  `Email Address`,
  `Virtual Airline`,
  `Virtual Airline IATA`,
  `Pricing`,
  `VAM/PHPVMS`,
  `Additional info`
) VALUES (
  :name,
  :email,
  :va,
  :vaiata,
  :pricing,
  :vamvms,
  :additionalinfo
);
');

$stmt->execute(array(
  ':name'           => $name,
  ':email'          => $email,
  ':va'             => $va,
  ':vaiata'         => $vaiata,
  ':pricing'        => $pricing,
  ':vamvms'         => $vamvms,
  ':additionalinfo' => $additionalinfo
));
```

Put it all together and you get:

```
<?php
if (
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && 
    array_key_exists('name', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('email', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('va', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('va-iata', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('pricing', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('vam-vms', $_POST) &&
    array_key_exists('add-info', $_POST)
  ) {
    /* put the $_POST values in variables */
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $va = $_POST['va'];
    $vaiata = $_POST['va-iata'];
    $pricing = $_POST['pricing'];
    $vamvms = $_POST['vam-vms'];
    $additionalinfo = $_POST['add-info'];

  try {
    /* database configuration */
    $servername = "host";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    /* establish a PDO connection */
    $dsn =  "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$servername;charset=utf8mb4";
    $db  =  new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $db  -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db  -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    /* Insert all the values in the request_site */
    $stmt = $db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO `request_site` (
      `Name`,
      `Email Address`,
      `Virtual Airline`,
      `Virtual Airline IATA`,
      `Pricing`,
      `VAM/PHPVMS`,
      `Additional info`
    ) VALUES (
      :name,
      :email,
      :va,
      :vaiata,
      :pricing,
      :vamvms,
      :additionalinfo
    );
    ');

    $stmt->execute(array(
      ':name'           => $name,
      ':email'          => $email,
      ':va'             => $va,
      ':vaiata'         => $vaiata,
      ':pricing'        => $pricing,
      ':vamvms'         => $vamvms,
      ':additionalinfo' => $additionalinfo
    ));

    echo 'New record created successfully';
  } catch(PDOException $ex) {
    /* handle database error */
    echo 'Connection failed: ', $ex->getMessage();
  }
} else {
  http_response_code(401);
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in my database... I don't get a message when I've submitted the form

Comment: @Jan - add the following statement before the `http_response_code`: `echo 'The method is either not a POST or one of the POST values is missing'; exit();`

Comment: It doesn't work.. I don't see anything in my database and it takes me to the next section of the page.